# JQuery - Get random text from variable with element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, variables

i am trying to get random text from variable but with elements,
Something like this:

```
var variableName = ' text';
var variableName2 = ' text';
var random = {
    'text' + variableName,
    'text2',
    'text3' + variableName2
}
```

i want to display it with `console.log('this is ' + randomText)`

Thanks,
Nikola

Comment: This question is still not clear. Two suggestions: 1. Give an example 2. Give more meaningful name to the variables and text to the strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
var variableName = ' test';
var variableName2 = ' test 1';
var arr = [
    'text ' + variableName,
    'text2',
    'text3 ' + variableName2
];

alert(arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)]);
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/by4cqx3r/